# Consulta ID Máximo TABLA

Tags: mysql

Estoy trabajando con MySQL , en donde tengo una tabla para ingreso de solicitudes. En mi código antes de ingresar una nueva solicitud, lo primero que hago es generar un Excel con toda la información ingresada y lo guardo, posterior a eso se ingresa la solicitud a la base de datos. El problema que tengo es que en el Excel tengo un campo con el ID de la solicitud y este dato recién lo tengo cuando guardo la solicitud.

Para verificar cual es el siguiente ID hago una consulta muy simple, pero al parecer esto no es bueno ya que si 2 usuarios están ingresando solicitudes al mismo tiempo tomaran el mismo ID y eso no seria bueno. Quisiera saber como manejar esto de la forma correcta para evitar duplicidad de ID.

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM PASANTIA
```

Comment: `LAST_INSERT_ID()` https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_last_insert_id.asp#:~:text=The%20LAST_INSERT_ID()%20function%20returns,or%20updated%20in%20a%20table.

Comment: O usas un ID automatico, o tenes que lockear la tabla para que no pase eso. O tenes que meterlo todo en un SP para que no se ejecute al mismo tiempo.

Comment: @Lobos siempre y cuando haya usado ID automaticos, cosa que no hizo porque su pregunta es como hacerlo ;)

Comment: Ejecute LAST_INSERT_ID y solo muestra ceros

Comment: Si dos usuarios están ingresando solicitudes al mismo tiempo, no deben tomar el mismo id, para eso las bases de datos tienen mecanismos propios vease bloqueo optimista o bloqueo pesimista, esa colisión de la q hablas no ocurre, los gestores de bases de datos nos libran de ellas, asi q la consulta q empleas es correcta

Comment: Definir el campo como auto_increment para que la BD gestione la asignación de nuevos ID. Para saber qué ID se asignó, usas métodos que te devuelvan el último valor insertado.

Comment: Tengo configurado mi campo ID como auto_increment

Answer (score -1):

Creo que lo que deberías de hacer es no llamar el último ID antes de ingresar los datos es preferible que te muestre cual ID asigno después de guardarlos así si dos usuarios ingresan datos les va arrojar a cada uno el ID que asigno

Comment: Que tal @Dego, bienvenido. Permíteme hacer un comentario, tu respuesta es buena, pero carece de elementos técnicos, te sugiero crear respuestas mínimas y reproducibles… la siguiente liga te puede ayudar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . En caso contrario, tu respuesta podría recibir reportes por "Baja calidad" o "No es una respuesta".

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/395539)